How To Clip/Fill A Shape with an image and not have it fixed
Below is my code, the problem im trying to solve is the image in the circle shape appears like a tiled background that is fixed in position as the shape moves around it, whereas the result I want is the shape itself is effectively a profile picture and the image moves inline with the shape's movements, not resembling a background fixed in position.
The same issue happens if I try to use clipShape(CustomCircleShape...
I am puzzled how to essentially turn the circle with its movements into an image.
struct WaveAnimationView: View {
    
    @State private var screenCoveragePercent = 45.0
    @State private var waveOffset = Angle(degrees: 0)
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            
            let shape = CustomCircleShape(offSet: Angle(degrees: waveOffset.degrees), percent: screenCoveragePercent)
            
            shape.fill(ImagePaint(image: Image("ryan"), sourceRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1), scale: 0.1)) .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
                        
        }
        .onAppear {
            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
                self.waveOffset = Angle(degrees: 360)
            }
        }
    }
    
}

struct CustomCircleShape: Shape {
    
    var offSet: Angle
    var percent: Double
    
    var animatableData: Double {
        get { offSet.degrees }
        set { offSet = Angle(degrees: newValue) }
    }
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var p = Path()
        
        let lowestWave = 0.02
        let highestWave = 1.00
        
        let newPercent = lowestWave + (highestWave - lowestWave) * (percent / 100)
        let waveHeight = 0.0020 * rect.height
        let yOffSet = CGFloat(1 - newPercent) * (rect.height - 4 * waveHeight) + 2 * waveHeight
        let startAngle = offSet
        let endAngle = offSet + Angle(degrees: 360 + 10)
            
        var circleCenter = CGPoint.zero
        
        for angle in stride(from: startAngle.degrees, through: endAngle.degrees, by: 5) {
            let x = CGFloat((angle - startAngle.degrees) / 360) * rect.width
            let y = yOffSet + waveHeight * CGFloat(sin(Angle(degrees: angle).radians))
            
            if x == rect.midX {
                circleCenter = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
            }
        }
        if circleCenter == .zero {
            circleCenter = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: yOffSet + waveHeight * CGFloat(sin(Angle(degrees: offSet.degrees + 180).radians)))
        }
        
        let circleRadius: CGFloat = 50
        p.addEllipse(in: CGRect(x: circleCenter.x - circleRadius, y: circleCenter.y - circleRadius, width: 2 * circleRadius, height: 2 * circleRadius))
        
        return p
    }
}

EDIT: Below is code showing the wave animation which the circle (which I'd like to be an image) is mimicking the movements of the wave.
struct WaveAnimation: View {
    
    @State private var screenCoveragePercent = 25.0
    @State private var waveOffset = Angle(degrees: 0)
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            
            let opacityOfWater = 0.25
            
            Wave(offSet: Angle(degrees: waveOffset.degrees), percent: screenCoveragePercent)
                .fill(Color.blue).opacity(opacityOfWater)
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
          
            CustomCircle(offSet: Angle(degrees: waveOffset.degrees), percent: screenCoveragePercent)
                .fill(Color.blue).opacity(1.0)
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
            
            InvisibleSlider(percent: $screenCoveragePercent)
        }
        .onAppear {
            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
                self.waveOffset = Angle(degrees: 360)
            }
        }
    }
    
}

struct CustomCircle: Shape {
    
    var offSet: Angle
    var percent: Double
    
    var animatableData: Double {
        get { offSet.degrees }
        set { offSet = Angle(degrees: newValue) }
    }
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var p = Path()
        
        let lowestWave = 0.02
        let highestWave = 1.00
        
        let newPercent = lowestWave + (highestWave - lowestWave) * (percent / 100)
        let waveHeight = 0.0020 * rect.height
        let yOffSet = CGFloat(1 - newPercent) * (rect.height - 4 * waveHeight) + 2 * waveHeight
        let startAngle = offSet
        let endAngle = offSet + Angle(degrees: 360 + 10)
            
        var circleCenter = CGPoint.zero
        
        for angle in stride(from: startAngle.degrees, through: endAngle.degrees, by: 5) {
            let x = CGFloat((angle - startAngle.degrees) / 360) * rect.width
            let y = yOffSet + waveHeight * CGFloat(sin(Angle(degrees: angle).radians))
            
            if x == rect.midX {
                circleCenter = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
            }
        }
        if circleCenter == .zero {
            circleCenter = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: yOffSet + waveHeight * CGFloat(sin(Angle(degrees: offSet.degrees + 180).radians)))
        }
        
        let circleRadius: CGFloat = 50
        p.addEllipse(in: CGRect(x: circleCenter.x - circleRadius, y: circleCenter.y - circleRadius, width: 2 * circleRadius, height: 2 * circleRadius))
        
        return p
    }
}

struct Wave: Shape {
    
    var offSet: Angle
    var percent: Double
    
    var animatableData: Double {
        get { offSet.degrees }
        set { offSet = Angle(degrees: newValue) }
    }
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var p = Path()
        
        let lowestWave = 0.02
        let highestWave = 1.00
        
        let newPercent = lowestWave + (highestWave - lowestWave) * (percent / 100)
        let waveHeight = 0.0020 * rect.height
        let yOffSet = CGFloat(1 - newPercent) * (rect.height - 4 * waveHeight) + 2 * waveHeight
        let startAngle = offSet
        let endAngle = offSet + Angle(degrees: 360 + 10)
        
        // Draw wave
        p.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: yOffSet + waveHeight * CGFloat(sin(offSet.radians))))
        for angle in stride(from: startAngle.degrees, through: endAngle.degrees, by: 5) {
            let x = CGFloat((angle - startAngle.degrees) / 360) * rect.width
            let y = yOffSet + waveHeight * CGFloat(sin(Angle(degrees: angle).radians))
            p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
        }
        
        p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: rect.height))
        p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.height))
        p.closeSubpath()
   
        return p
    }
}


You are doing all kinds of calculations about where the circle should be, in path(in:). Don't do this. The shape should not change its position relative to the rect. Then, make a Image(...).clipShape(...), and animate the offset of that. Can you describe what kind of animation you want to achieve?

I'm creating a water/wave animation and trying to place an image on top of the wave so it looks like it's floating/bobbing in sync with the wave. I've copied the code I used from creating the wave and turned it into a circle so that the movements are in sync with the wave. I've added/edited to add that code to show that.

Your code is animating the path of the shape, relative to its bounds (the rect parameter).
You should instead create an Image(...).clipShape(Circle()), and add an .offset(y: ...) to it. Then you can animate the y offset of this image as a whole.
I would design Wave so that it fills the entirety of the given rect. That is, remove percent. How much space the wave covers can be adjusted using a Spacer in a VStack.
struct Wave: Shape {
    var offset: Angle
    let maxHeight: CGFloat
    
    var animatableData: Double {
        get { offset.degrees }
        set { offset = Angle(degrees: newValue) }
    }
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        Path { p in
            p.move(to: rect.origin)
            for deg in stride(from: 0, through: 360, by: 5) {
                let angle = Angle.degrees(Double(deg)) + offset
                let height = sin(angle.radians) * maxHeight
                p.addLine(to: .init(x: Double(deg) / 360 * rect.size.width + rect.minX, y: height + rect.minY))
            }
            p.addLine(to: .init(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
            p.addLine(to: .init(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
            p.closeSubpath()
        }
    }
}

Now we put the image on top of it. The y offset of the image is calculated mathematically. See how the implementation of yOffset corresponds to the implementation of Wave.path(in:).
struct WaveAndCircle: View, Animatable {
    var waveOffset: Angle
    let maxWaveHeight: CGFloat = 20

    var animatableData: Double {
        get { waveOffset.degrees }
        set { waveOffset = Angle(degrees: newValue) }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            Wave(offset: waveOffset, maxHeight: maxWaveHeight)
                .fill(.blue.opacity(0.25))
            Image("my_image")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                // change the alignment guide of the image, so that its center
                // is aligned to the top of the wave
                .alignmentGuide(.top, computeValue: { dimension in
                    dimension[VerticalAlignment.center]
                })
                .offset(y: yOffset)
        }
    }
    
    var yOffset: CGFloat {
        let offsetAngle = waveOffset + .degrees(180)
        let sinResult = sin(offsetAngle.radians)
        return sinResult * maxWaveHeight
    }   
}

And finally, putting everything together.
struct WaveAnimation: View {
    
    @State private var screenCoveragePercent = 25.0
    @State private var waveOffset = Angle(degrees: 0)
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            VStack {
                Spacer().frame(height: geo.size.height * (1 - screenCoveragePercent))
                WaveAndCircle(waveOffset: waveOffset)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
                self.waveOffset = Angle(degrees: 360)
            }
        }
    }
}


Wow, fantastic. Is there a way I could randomise the wave height so that it changes and looks more natural, rather than having a fixed maxWaveHeight of 20?

@dub what’s “more natural”? Think of a mathematical way to express that, and implement it in Wave, and change yOffset accordingly.

Well essentially I'm asking how would I change maxWaveHeight: CGFloat = 2.5 to Int.random(in: 1..5) so that the height of the wave changes as it animates?

@dub Ah I see. I think you would need maxWaveHeight to be a part of the animatableData (use an AnimatablePair), and then animate maxWaveHeight periodically to a different value. If you still struggle, I'd suggest posting a new question.

Yes indeed, thanks, it would be a different branch of the original issue.
